# Multiple directives for the same module in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a module for my angular app, and I have two similar directives that I have associated with both.

One (whenScrolled) is triggered when the scroll reaches the bottom of the page for infinite pagination. The other (fromTop) triggers either a "top" or "bottom" that can be used to hide/show a "go to top" link on the page. This is how I have them set up:

```
angular.module('scroll', []).directive('fromTop', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attributes) {
    var raw = element[0]
    var scrollDistance = Math.round(window.outerHeight)

    window.onscroll = function() {
      console.log(window.pageYOffset, raw.scrollHeight + scrollDistance)
      if (window.pageYOffset >= raw.scrollHeight + scrollDistance) {
        scope.position = 'bottom'
        scope.$apply(attributes.fromTop)
      } else {
        scope.position = 'top'
        scope.$apply(attributes.fromTop)
      }
    }
  }
}).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attributes) {
    var raw = element[0]
    var scrollDistance = Math.round(window.outerHeight)

    window.onscroll = function() {
      //console.log(window.pageYOffset, raw.scrollHeight - scrollDistance)
      if (window.pageYOffset >= raw.scrollHeight - scrollDistance) {
        scope.$apply(attributes.whenScrolled)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. it seems that the "whenScrolled" directive is overwriting the "fromTop" one and fromTop never gets called. However, if I delete "whenScrolled", "fromTop" gets called just fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with angular.js at all.

Your problem: You overwrite the `window.onscroll` function every time you attach a directive to a DOM element, which has the effect that only the last of you applied directives will work. There can only be one `onscroll` function.

You need to work around this limitation some how:

- Using a angular service which add captures the `onscroll` and then propagate the changes to all your directives.
- Use a JavaScript library which does the same.
- After some digging the third option: Angular has `bind` function which does the same. As option 2.